# Add event listener to all document children by tag name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to translate this jquery to vanilla js:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
    //do something
});
```

I've tried with

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if(e.target.tagName === 'A')
    {
        //do something
    }
});
```

But it's not working if the element clicked is a child of an `a`, for example

```
<a href="...">
    <!-- if I click on the image, e.target.tagName === 'IMG' -->
    <img src="img.jpg">
</a>
```

I can't use `document.getElementsByTagName('a')`, because It should work even with those created dynamically.

Also, I'd need to access the `href` property of the `a`.

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: use `e.currentTarget`. This may help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Comparison_of_Event_Targets

Answer (score 2):

In modern browsers you can use [Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) - Not supported in IE

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (Element.prototype.closest) {
    if (e.target.closest('a')) {
      console.log('found')
    }
  } else {
    //else the long way
    var el = e.target;
    while (el && el.tagName != 'A') {
      el = el.parentNode;
    }
    if (el) {
      console.log('found')
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="...">
  This and image
  <img src="img.jpg">
</a>
Not here
```

Answer (score 1):

### Take the DOM for a Walk

You have a anchor tag that contains an image and you want catch click events.

The currentTarget property (as suggested in a comment) is not useful since the handler is attached to document, i.e., currentTarget = document.

The solution is to catch clicks on the image and then walk up the DOM tree to check if the parent element is an anchor tag.

The code below illustrates how you might accomplish this check using a while loop.  It also displays target, currentTarget, and parentElement. As you can see, clicking on the text within the link produces different output than clicking on the image.

**Run the snippet to try**

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var t = e.target;
  while (t) {
    if (t.tagName === 'A') {

      // do something ...

      debug.innerHTML += (
        'target = ' + e.target +
        '\ncurrentTarget = ' + e.currentTarget +
        '\nparentElement.tagName = ' + t.tagName + '\n'
      );

      break;
    }
    t = t.parentElement;
  }


});


// dynamically add link with image
var a = document.createElement('A');
a.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
a.innerHTML = 'Click Me!<br><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50">';
document.getElementById('content').appendChild(a);
```

```css
img {width:100px;height:50px;background-color:aliceblue;}
```

```html
<span id="content"></span>
<xmp id="debug"></xmp>
```